# iframe с содержимым по вкусу

Tags: html, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток.

Хочу вставить в определенную страницу `iframe` (`test.html`), чье содержимое будет меняться и изначально мне неизвестно. Требуется внутри `test.html` запретить дополнительные:

- `iframe`
- `JS`
- изображения
- `*.swf`
- `JQ`
- `Java`
- доп. библиотеки
- include
- php код
- и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть атрибут [sandbox](http://htmlbook.ru/html/iframe/sandbox), но он работает только в Хроме и Сафари...

Comment: классно. буду копать в эту сторону